# An (open?) problem about a sequence of nested sub-matrices and their determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus

I had an idea. Let us start with an example. Consider the matrix
$$ A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right] $$
It is invertible, since its determinant is $1$. Now consider the sequence of the upper-left square submatrices:

$$ A \left[ 1 \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \end{array} \right], \quad 
A \left[ 1,2 \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right], \quad 
A \left[ 1,2,3 \right] = A $$
The second matrix is **singular** (its determinant is zero). However, we can find other sequence of nested "central" sub-matrices such that all of them are invertible:
$$ A \left[ 1 \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \end{array} \right], \quad 
A \left[ 1,3 \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right], \quad 
A \left[ 1,2,3 \right] = A $$
I wonder whether such a sequence always exists. I need some notation to enunciate the problem.

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. Given $S \subset \left[ 1,n \right]$, we denote $A\left[ S \right]$ the matrix obtained from $A$ by only taking the rows and columns whose index are in $S$. Formally,
$$ A\left[ S \right] = R_S \, A \, R^t_S, $$
where $S = \lbrace s_1 < \ldots < s_m \rbrace$ and $R_s$ is the $m \times n$ matrix with $1$ at the positions $(i, s_i)$ and zero elsewhere.

**Question:** Let $A$ be a regular $n \times n$ matrix. Under which conditions there exist a nested sequence
$$ S_1 \subset S_2 \subset \cdots \subset S_n = \left[ 1,n \right], \quad |S_i| = i$$
such that each $A\left[ S_i \right]$ is regular? How to compute such a sequence? How many sequences are there?

It is trivial that the matrix must have a non-zero entry in its diagonal. Does anybody know if this problem has already been studied?

I have made several numerical experiments (with $n < 6$) and it seems that almost every sequence verify the condition.

Comment: To compute the number of such sequences, you might be looking at some sort of matroid, but I'll let others comment on such an application.

Comment: posted also at MO http://mathoverflow.net/questions/203271/an-open-problem-about-a-sequence-of-nested-sub-matrices-and-their-determinant

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a matrix and suppose that $\dim(\text{image}(A))=k$.  This means that there are $k$ independent columns in $A$.  Let $0\leq r\leq k$.  Choose $r$ independent columns in $A$.

Now, consider these $r$ columns in a new (sub-matrix) $B$ of $A$.  Since the rank of $B$ is $r$, it has $r$ independent rows.  Choose $r$ independent rows in $B$.

Let $C$ be the sub-matrix of $B$ formed from these independent rows of $B$.  This is a square matrix of size $r\times r$ which is invertible because its rows are independent.

To count the number of such sequences may be more challenging.

This does not answer the question posed by the OP, but is a substitute, since the invertible matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ fails the conditions.  The answer above is the same after applying a permutation, perhaps.

Comment: I do not think that this answers the question. You consider first **any** $k$ columns and then **some** $k$ rows. In the question, the indices of the columns and the rows must coincide: we must take **some** $k$ columns and the "same" arrows.

Comment: You are correct that it does not answer the question, as stated in the last lines - it answers a related question.  The challenge in the OP is that it depends on the choice of order in the bases, which makes the statement much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's true. Consider the matrix
$$\left[\matrix{0&1&0\cr 0&0&1\cr1&0&0\cr}\right]$$
which is invertible. There is no such sequence of "central" submatrices.

Comment: In fact this fails when all the entries in the diagonal are zero. I will edit my question to avoid this.